# Как обучается нейросеть R-CNN?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Есть популярный алгоритм для распознания образов - R-CNN. Задача найти определенный объект на изображении и отнести его к определенному классу. К примеру мы хотим распознавать номера домов. Наша задача выделить область с цифрой и определить что это за цифра (один, два или три...). Я понял, что для таких задач нередко используется алгоритм R-CNN. Он состоит из нескольких этапов:

1. Разбиение изображения на области, где вероятней всего находится нужный объект. Это происходит с помощью алгоритма selection search.
2. Мы пропускаем полученные фрагменты через нейросеть, которая выделяет набор признаков.
   Вопрос: непонятно что происходит начиная с этого момента. Как происходит дальнейшее взаимодействие с полученными признаками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально, ответ на ваш вопрос №2 -  *"Как происходит дальнейшее взаимодействие с полученными признаками?"* выглядит так: По имеющимся значениям признаков происходит решение классической задачи классификации.

Однако, я понимаю, что не этого вы ожидаете. Но ваш вопрос №2 это как раз и есть общая формулировака задачи распознавания  и классификации объектов на рисунке с помощью нейросети.

Дать ответе на форуме  на столь общий вопрос "как нейросеть распознает картинку" -  понятно что невозможно. Поэтому могу вам лишь посоветовать пару неплохих статей на эту тему, проработав которые у вас должно сложиться соответствующее представление. А потом, когда что-то останется неясным, вы можете вернуться сюда уже с конкретными вопросами, на которые вам дадут конкретные практические ответы.

```
https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-object-detection-using-keras-and-opencv-ddfe89bb3c3
https://towardsdatascience.com/r-cnn-for-object-detection-a-technical-summary-9e7bfa8a557c
https://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-with-deep-learning/
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321478922_Accurate_object_classification_and_detection_by_faster-RCNN
https://towardsdatascience.com/computer-vision-creating-a-classifier-using-convolutions-pooling-and-tensorflow-7e75d809acbc
https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-data-science-422855878d2a
https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-web-application-for-predicting-apple-leaf-diseases-using-pytorch-and-flask-413f9fa9276a
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/07/computer-vision-implementing-mask-r-cnn-image-segmentation/
```

Comment: Мой вопрос в том, как обучить данный классификатор, как определить для него метки. Ведь selection search выбирает произвольные области. Надо ли нам создавать метку отдеьно для каждого сегмента?

Comment: Задача классификации - это задача из класса "обучение с учителем".  Каждый выделенный объект нейросеть обрабатывает по сути как отдельную картинку. Соответственно, если вы хотите свою нейросеть обучить - вы должны ей скормить пару тысяч картинок, на каждой из которых выделить объект и дать его метку-описание. P.S, Не могу понять, почему кто-то минусует этот ответ. Хотел бы услышать обоснование.

Comment: Просто я пытаюсь понять, как работает данный алгоритм. Мы выделили сегменты. Для каждого сегмента создается набор признаков. И тут ключевой момент: необходимо определить к какому классу относится сегмент. Возможно это фон.  И как обучать такой классификатор (SVM) не совсем понятно. P. S. Ваш ответ не минусовал

Comment: "На последнем этапе вектора признаков регионов обрабатываются SVM, проводящими классификацию объектов, по одной SVM на каждый домен."  Непонятна суть этого предложения.

Comment: Во-первых, SVM -  это только один из широкого спектра возможных классификаторов. Не всегда самый лучший. Во-вторых, он обучается так-же как и все другие классификаторы - путем подачи предварительного тренировочного множества объектов (в данном случае - картинок) с их метками. По одной на каждый домен - очевидно имеется, что для каждого возможного типа объекта строится свой классификатор, а в рабочем режиме проверяется, какой из них "сработает" на вашем объекте.

Comment: Просто у меня есть набор, где содержаться изображения цифр и соответствующие метки. Если я обучу SVM на данном наборе, то возможно он будет работать некорректно для произвольных сегментов.

Comment: Разумеется, так и будет. А в чем сомнение?  Впрочем, что такое "сегменты" я не понял :-), но если вы обучили на цифрах, то именно цифры он и будет распознавать. Не буквы, не иероглифы и не "пляшущих человечков"